# SQL Server stored procedure cannot save because of an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server procedure (parameter values are temporarily hard-corded):

```
DECLARE @ComCod AS VARCHAR(2) = '15'
DECLARE @LocCod AS VARCHAR(2) = '01'
DECLARE @PetDat AS VARCHAR(8) = '20180731'

DECLARE @CurrentBatchNo AS INT 

EXECUTE @CurrentBatchNo = Accounts.dbo.fnApp_GetCurrentBatchNo @ComCode = @ComCod,
                                                               @LocCode = @LocCod

INSERT INTO GL_Batch_Details
            (Company_Code,
             Location_Code,
             Fiscal_Year,
             Fiscal_Month,
             Batch_No,
             Entry_No,
             Source_Code,
             Line_No,
             Account_Code,
             Transaction_Date,
             Debit_Amount,
             Credit_Amount,
             Reference,
             Narration,
             Batch_Status,
             Delete_Status)
             VALUES(@ComCod /* Company_Code */,
                    @LocCod /* Location_Code */,
                    SUBSTRING(Accounts.dbo.fnApp_GetFinancialDates(@PetDat),1,4) /* Fiscal_Year */,
                    SUBSTRING(Accounts.dbo.fnApp_GetFinancialDates(@PetDat),9,2) /* Fiscal_Month */,
                    @CurrentBatchNo /* Batch_No */,
                    1 /* Entry_No */,
                    'GLC1' /* Source_Code */,
                    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PettyHeader.HPetComCode,
                                                       PettyHeader.HPetLocCode,
                                                       PettyHeader.HPetDate) /* Line_No */,
                            PettyDetail.DPetAcNo /* Account_Code */,
                            PettyDetail.DPetDate /* Transaction_Date */,
                            PettyDetail.DPetAmount /* Debit_Amount */,
                            0.00 /* Credit_Amount */,
                            PettyHeader.HPetPayee /* Reference */,
                            CAST(PettyHeader.HPetVouNo as varchar) +
                                ' '+
                                PettyDetail.DPetDetail /* Narration */
                            FROM PettyHeader
                                 INNER JOIN PettyDetail
                                            ON PettyHeader.HPetComCode = PettyDetail.DPetComCode AND
                                               PettyHeader.HPetLocCode = PettyDetail.DPetLocCode AND
                                               PettyHeader.HPetDate = PettyDetail.DPetDate AND
                                               PettyHeader.HPetVouNo = PettyDetail.DPetVouNo
                                               WHERE (PettyHeader.HPetComCode = @ComCod) AND
                                                     (PettyHeader.HPetLocCode = @LocCod) AND
                                                     (YEAR(PettyHeader.HPetDate) = YEAR(CONVERT(date, @PetDat,111))) AND
                                                     (MONTH(PettyHeader.HPetDate) = MONTH(CONVERT(date, @PetDat, 111)))),
                    '1' /* Batch_Status */,
                    'F' /* Delete_Status */)
```

Function code below

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnApp_GetCurrentBatchNo] 
    (@ComCode VARCHAR(2),
     @LocCode VARCHAR(2))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @CurrentBatchNo INT

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @CurrentBatchNo = (SELECT (Last_Updated_Batch_No + 1)
                              FROM Provisional_Posting_Log
                              WHERE Company_Code = @ComCode 
                                AND Location_Code = @LocCode)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @CurrentBatchNo
END
```

While saving my procedure following errors are generated:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>
> Msg 109, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Can someone please help me fix these errors?

Comment: You have an INSERT that lists the fields to be populated, and then lists the values to be used to populate those fields.  The 8th of these is a SELECT statement.  That would be okay if the SELECT returned a single value, which could be assigned to Liine_No but you are selecting 7 values.  Which one do you intend to be stored in Line_No?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to populate seven fields with one SELECT.  You need a separate SELECT for each value.  ...  Or you could replace the whole VALUES clause with a single SELECT.

Comment: Dear David Dubois, I solve my problem by populating all fields with one SELECT. Thank You very much